Driving power LED using Optocoupler from LM3914 or LM3915 output
I am trying to drive a set of power LEDs (12V, 10 or 20 watts) to make a large audio level indicator. I didn't understand the features of LM3914 or LM3915 very well from it's datasheet. However there was a one-liner description which says it can efficiently drive Optocoupler based Relay circuits. Can someone please help me confirm if the following circuit is good to work?

(input side circuitry is not shown)
I also have few questions.

Is PC817 a good choice of optocoupler here?
Do I need R2 or is LM3914's current is within the limit to directly power the PC817's LED?
Is R1=1K too high?
Is a Darlington transistor like TIP122 overkill here? Is there a better alternative (like MOSFET) to replace it, which can drive 1-2
amp load? How would that circuit be?


FYI, TI does not make the LM3914/15 anymore, what you can buy now are Chinese clones. Some clones are good, some are not. You may want to breadboard your design with plain LEDs before you go too far.

@Mattman944 I am aware of this and have the exact same experience with the Chinese clones. These ICs do not behave consistently. Thanks for pointing out though.


Not familiar with Pic817. Do you have a datasheet link. Do you mean PC817, originally manufactured by Sharp, perhaps? I suggest a C or D rank unit.

The current can be programmed from 2mA to 30mA, according to the datasheet, so pick something like 5mA.

It won't work as shown. The phototransistor provides a conductive path, it does not supply voltage for the Darlington. Connect the collector of the opto to +12 and the emitter to the R1. That will provide about 10mA of base current, so 1kΩ is okay.

A MOSFET would be smaller and cheaper and would run cooler. You'd need another resistor from the gate to ground.



My bad, it's PC817, not PIC. Corrected my question.

Just a pull-down resistor is good enough to replace it with a MOSFET? The 1K resistor from optocoupler's emitter remains same?

You can replace the 1k with a short and use a 3kΩ pulldown.

The issue in your circuit is that your opto connects the base of TIP122 to its emitter, which turns off TIP122 instead of turning it on. Also, a darlington power transistor will have quite high voltage across it when it's on, say 1V at least, so your 12V LED may not light to full brightness. Using a MOSFET would be preferable, as you can select one with low enough RdsON.


Left circuit:

LM3914's outputs are current sinks to ground, and the value of the current can be set by an external resistor. So you can use resistor R1 to convert LM3914's output current to a voltage referenced to the positive supply, and a P-channel MOSFET, which will conduct and light the LEDs when LM3914 outputs current.
The MOSFET has a Vgs limit, usually at 20V. Since you're using 12V, no special protection is needed.

Middle circuit:

I think this is what you wanted to do. When LM3914 outputs current, the optocoupler LED conducts, which turns on its transistor, which drives the gate of a N-channel MOSFET to the positive supply and turns it on.

Right circuit:

If you don't want isolation, then an optocoupler isn't necessary and you can simply use a PNP transistor to invert the LM3914 output. Here I wired it as current mirror, supposing LM3914 is configured to sink 1mA, the transistor will also source around 1mA and turn on the MOSFET.
In all circuits, a capacitor can be added (C1) to slow down MOSFET switching and avoid emitting noise. The MOSFET can require a gate resistor to prevent oscillation or other misbehavior.

Thanks so much for responding. In your left and right circuits, you have connected the output of LM3914 to +ve via a transistor, I never tried this before. With all the intelligent handling LM3914 datasheet claims, does this work? I suppose, LM3914 is not expecting a one way conduction on it' output (i.e. through a diode) for its correct operation.

I am actually looking for isolation. Even though for simplicity I have shown same power source, I may actually power the LM3914 with 12V, but the LED's can be a bit higher rated, say 24V. So middle circuit looks optimal for what I need. Just asking in this relation, if you have time can you please show if with little modification, the MOSFET can be replaced with a TRIAC like BT136 to operate an AC mains load like incandescent bulbs?

LM3914 output is a constant current sink intended to drive a LED, but you can use it for other things like driving a transistor or the LED inside an opto coupler. The important thing is that the output sinks current to ground, and is supposed to drive a LED connected to the positive supply. Yes you can use a triac too, you need to use an opto-triac like MOC3022. It's similar to an opto coupler, but the output is a low power triac instead of a transistor. Then you use that to drive a larger triac. If you google "opto triac schematics" you'll find plenty of designs.
